# Login with Enterprise Principal Name using sssd AD backend in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: sssd, ubuntu-14.04, active-directory

I’m running `sssd` version 1.11 with the AD backend in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (1.11.5-1ubuntu3) to authenticate users from Active Directory running on Windows Server 2012 R2, and I’m trying to achieve logins with the User Principal Name for all users of the domain. But the UPN are always Enterprise Principal Names.

Let-me illustrate the problem with my user account:

> ```
> Domain: local.example.com
> sAMAccountName: ferrao
> UPN: ferrao@example.com (there’s no local in the UPN)
> ```

I can successfully login with the `sAMAccountName` atribute, which is fine, but I can’t login with ferrao@example.com which is my UPN. The optimum solution for me is to allow logins from `sAMAccountName` and the UPN (User Principal Name). If’s not possible, the UPN should be the right way instead of the `sAMAccountName`.

Another annoyance is the homedir pattern with those options in `sssd.conf`:

```
default_shell = /bin/bash
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
```

What I would like to achieve is separated home directories from the EPN. For example:

```
/home/example.com/user
/home/whatever.example.com/user
```

But with this pattern I can’t map the way I would like to do. I’ve looked through man pages and was unable to find any answers for this issues.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation the conclusion was that as today it's impossible to implement this setup using `sssd`.

There are two patches that should be done, and they are acknowledged by the `sssd` developers team.

Allow email addresses in User Principal
https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/ticket/1749

Home directory with template expansion:
https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/ticket/2340

So there's no viable solution using `sssd` at this time.